# Error in polyroot(x) : unimplemented type 'closure' in 'polyroot'

Tags: r, function, closures

I want to maximize the following function of x using polyroot but every time I receive the error : "Error in polyroot(x) : unimplemented type 'closure' in 'polyroot'"

Why is this so? What does type closure means in this specific context? How can I solve this problem?

MWE :

```
z = function(x){-34820000+0.55*x^3}
polyroot(z,c(0,0,1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is `polyroot` in base R, read `?polyroot` to find out how to use the function.  It takes *one* argument which is a vector of the coefficients starting with the constant so:

```
p <- c(-34820000, 0, 0, 0.55)  # polynomial coefficients
r <- polyroot(p)  # roots
```

We can check this using:

```
sapply(r, z)
```